# pass named and unnamed arguments to stateless component

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, redux-form, react-props

Is there a way to pass named and unnamed parameters to the same stateless component.

so for instance....

This works.

```
const renderSoftwareForm = ({ fields, meta: { error, submitFailed } }) => ( 
<div>sample</div>
);
```

And this works

```
const renderSoftwareForm = (props) => ( 
<div>sample</div>
);
```

but I have parameters besides just the props from the parent that need to be passed in as well....

is there a syntax that allows for something more like this?

```
const renderSoftwareForm = (props, { fields, meta: { error, submitFailed } }) => ( 
<div>sample</div> 
);
```

Comment: Every data that you want to pass from the parent component to a child component must be passed through props. Also, the functional components only get called with the props argument.

Comment: How do you use `renderSoftwareForm`? I think that decides what you can do.

Comment: It renders a group of redux-form Field elements. They need access to all props passed in from the parents, but also need access to {field, meta: {error, submitFailed}} in order to do error handling with Redux-form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do this.

```
const renderSoftwareForm = ({ fields, meta: { error, submitFailed }, ...props }) => ( 
<div>sample</div>
);
```

This explicitly handles the `fields` and `meta` properties, and any properties not explicitly handled are part of the `props` object.

This requires [object rest spread support](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread), which isn't yet part of the JavaScript standard, but [can be enabled via Babel plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/) (and this is commonly done in React development).